# Elasticsearch two sets of terms against two fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch to return docs that have different terms in two fields. Not knowing how to write this it would be something like this:

```
query:
    field1: "term set #1"
    field2: "very different term set #2"
```

Ideally the term sets would be arrays of strings. I'd like all terms and field hits to be ORed so the best docs would have all hits in each field but if any field had none, that would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Terms Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and `bool should` for achieving this assuming that you want to match the exact values without analysis. The beauty of `Terms Query` is that it implicitly works with an array of values and it implicitly is an `OR` operation.

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "field1": [
                     "field1 value1",
                     "field1 value2",
                     "field1 value3"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "field2": [
                     "field2 value1",
                     "field2 value2",
                     "field2 value3"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the answer. I don't want an analyzer. The terms aren't from text and should never be tokenized either in the query or in ES storage. To make sure an analyzer is not used in query or when looking at the terms so I need to do anything else, maybe in index config?

Comment: A related question is how to upsert the doc terms as an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by trying something like the query below. It is a very simple query that will find docs, whose `field1` matches `term set one` OR `field2` matches `very different term set two`. You don't need to specify an array of terms because ES will do it for you under the hood during the analysis phase, i.e. it will take `term set one` and break it apart into the tokens `term`, `set` and `one` and match them against `field1`. Similarly, for `field2`.

Also note I've specified the `or` operator even though it's the default just to illustrate that there is an `and`, too, shall you need it at some point.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field1": "term set one",
            "operator": "or"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field2": "very different term set two",
            "operator": "or"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: This looks pretty close. They aren't text terms so I don't want them to go through the analyzer. I need something like a Solr Multi-valued field